# What is the value of passing table value parameters into SQL CLR stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a stored procedure to write where I need only two attributes out of a field. Most likely, it will only be working on one, maybe two or three fields at a time. It's also supposed to be a CLR stored procedure.

As a beginner in SQL, it seems to me that passing a table value parameter is overkill, however since this is for work, and a relatively big company, I'm wondering if there are other considerations to make? What exactly is the value in using a table value parameter as opposed to a normal one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for CLR outlined in your question, however there are definitely uses for TVPs.

I have seen comma separated lists being passed into SQL stored procedures, TVPs could be utilized there for better type checking and structure.

It also helps with enterprise level robustness; I worked on something that would attempt 1.5 million inserts within ~1 hour. Doing this with individual inserts (a proc that accepted a bunch of scalar parameters) was resource intensive and very, very slow; when converted to perform bulk inserts with Table Valued Parameters the operation completed in about 1/5 the time.